# Word that means a combination of respect, empathy and being concerned for others' well being

Tags: single-word-requests

What I'm trying to convey is the desire not to do harm to another person because you value not harming people.

"Respect" is almost there but it carries the additional meaning of respect for authority and sort of implies an unbalanced relationship.

"Empathy" also captures something of this but empathy seems more about emotions that are shared rather then behavior.

"Concern" also feels wrong as it seems to be too fleeting.

If I was to use it in a sentence it would be something like "The moral of the story is that a relationship without XXXX results in tragedy no matter how much the people involved love each other".

Comment: *Benevolence*, perhaps?

Comment: To me, this sounds like sheer _kindness_. _Graciousness_ or _magnanimity_ might also be worth considering.

Comment: Tenderness or compassion maybe?

Comment: What about solicitude?

Comment: @m.a.a. I think kindness captures the idea I'm going for best.  Can you write it as an answer to I can select it.  The other suggestions where all good as well.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Answer added. Should we go ahead and remove our comments now?

Comment: What about _caring_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this sounds like sheer *kindness*, i.e. the quality of being *kind*.

> **kind**
>
> - generous, helpful, and thinking about other people's feelings
>        not causing harm or damage
>
> from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind)

---

> **kind**
>
> 1. having a friendly or generous nature or attitude
> 2. helpful to others or to another ⇒ a kind deed
> 3. considerate or humane
> 4. cordial; courteous (esp in the phrase kind regards)
> 5. pleasant; agreeable; mild ⇒ a kind climate
> 6. informal beneficial or not harmful ⇒ a detergent that is kind to the hands
> 7. archaic loving
>
> from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kind)

*[Graciousness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/graciousness)* or *[magnanimity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/magnanimous)* might also be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ***understanding*** works here.

> "The moral of the story is that a relationship without
> ***understanding*** results in tragedy no matter how much the people involved love each other"

ODO:

> **[understanding](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/understanding)**
> *NOUN*
> **2** Sympathetic awareness or tolerance:
>
> ‘he wrote with understanding and affection of the people of Dent’
> ‘Tolerance and
> understanding develops between Ruth and other members of the
> household.’

M-W:

> **[understanding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understanding)**
> *noun*
> **3 a** :  friendly or harmonious relationship
>
> a relationship based on mutual *understanding*

Answer (score 0):

[***humanism***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humanism)

*(Collins Dictionary)*

> 4. interest in the welfare of people
>
> "The moral of the story is that a relationship without **humanism** results in tragedy no matter how much the people involved love each other".

Comment: I'm a little skeptical. I think that a person can be a humanist, but I'm not sure whether they can have humanism.

Comment: @ktm5124 - It works fine.  Try looking up "her humanism" in Google Books.  Also note that it's the relationship's humanism, not the individual person's.

Answer (score 0):

I think [goodwill](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/goodwill) would work.

> a feeling of benevolence, approval, and kindly interest

If we were to use it in your sentence,

> The moral of the story is that a relationship without goodwill results in tragedy no matter how much the people involved love each other.

Answer (score 0):

Although almost all of the suggested words seem appropriate, however, in case they fail to meet your needs, then you could try “politeness” or “courtesy”.

***Polite***
(Cambridge Online Dictionary)

> behaving in a way that is socially correct and shows understanding of and care for other people's feelings.

***Courtesy***
(Cambridge Online Dictionary)

> polite behaviour, or a polite action or remark